# Splash Screen not displaying with PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

When I load my application is does not display the splash screen I have set. Here is my `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
            xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
            id        = "com.Mobile.test"
            versionCode=""
            version   = "1.0">
            <name>Mobile</name>
            <description>
            </description>
            <author href="www.mobile.net" email="editor@mobile.net">
    SMD
            </author>
            <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
            <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
            <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
            <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
            <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
            <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
            <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
            <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
            <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
            <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
            <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
            <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
            <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
            <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
            <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
            <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
            <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
            <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
            <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
            <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
            <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
            <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
            <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
            <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
            <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
            <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
            <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
            <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
            <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
            <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
            <gap:platform name="android" />
            <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />
            <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
            <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
            <gap:splash src="img/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
            <gap:splash src="img/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
            <gap:splash src="img/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
        </widget>
```

I have also tried:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

with the splash screen titled "splash" and in the root folder with the index.html with no luck

The splash screens are sized as:

```
LDPI:
Portrait: 200x320px
Landscape: 320x200px
MDPI:
Portrait: 320x480px
Landscape: 480x320px
HDPI:
Portrait: 480x800px
Landscape: 800x480px
```

Can someone make a recommendation as to how to fix this problem? I am not wrapping this application locally, strictly using **Phone Gap** Build.

Answer (score 2):

I compare  some project for me , i implemented Splash screen in it with your `config.xml` i found you missing this line :

```
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="6000" />
```

and this plugin

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

try this and feed me back

Comment: i found you add the plugin try to re order the plugin element at the end of your xml

Comment: Mohammed- I tried it with the additional methods with no luck. Should I revert back to the default splash.png in the root folder?

Comment: no , look this my implementation in the splash screen image 
<!-- Splash screen -->
<gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"  width="320" height="426" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  width="320" height="470" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  width="480" height="640" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="720" height="960" />

Comment: I modified mine to match yours with no luck either...Does this have to do with the fact that I am uploading and having PhoneGap Build do the wrap?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47619/discussion-between-bacon2305-and-mohammed-momn)

Comment: hey i have same issue. i post this. this i link please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425816/splash-screen-not-come-when-in-build-from-cloud-phonegap-form-eclipse-i-run-in