# splash screen not come when in build from cloud phonegap. form eclipse i run in emulator its work prefect

Tags: android, cordova, cloud, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i build phonegap project with help of CLI. and i import that in eclipse. add plugin of splash screen. prefect work in emulator.
Then after i want that apps in ios and windows. so for that i go for cloud of phonegap. i upload eclipse code. 
but splash screen not display. directly goes in main screen by cloud bulider.
this is config.xml file which path is:- hello4\platforms\android\res\xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.wtow.hello4" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <name>HelloWorld4</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
```

i am edit with some changes
config.xml file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
version = "1.0.0">
<name>Hotel</name>
<description>
This apps for hotel
</description>
<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
PhoneGap Team
</author>
<!--
If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation" value="default" /> <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" /> <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" /> <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" /> <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" /> <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" /> <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" /> <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" /> <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" /> <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<!--
Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
-->
<!-- Plugins -->
<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<!-- Third party plugins -->
<!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
<!--
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
-->
<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/drawable/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/drawable-hdpi/icon" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />



<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
<string>100</string>
</gap:config-file>
<!--
Define access to external domains.
<access /> - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
<access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
-->
<access origin="*"/>
<!--
<access origin="http://phonegap.com" /> - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
<access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" /> - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
<access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
-->
</widget>
```

===================
and here is screen shot of which folder i upload to cloud phonegap build
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload to Phonegap build services your config.xml file should be in www/config.xml. Also the name space for your config should be xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0."  Look here for further info: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics

Comment: thank you for ans, config.xml i copy from res/xml or create new one?

Comment: I believe that phonegap builds does the copying for you. I think you might be confused with building locally vs with phonegap build. Phonegap build will build and copy the files to the their necessary locations. So dont worry about you adding it to res/xml file. Simply make sure that your config.xml file is correct. Also read this: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens. One thing that did not realise is that you must include a splash.png file, or else it will not work.

Comment: Here is an example of a config.xml file https://github.com/jozzhart/phonegap-ionic/blob/master/config.xml. Also important that you add a splash.png file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385308/phonegap-build-not-showing-splashscreen

Comment: ohhh woww.. you are to good and thank for my help. i will check within 2 days. then after i will make right your ans.. really thank brother.

Comment: hey i am really confuse, i develop first in android eclipse and then i build to cloud for all platform ok. i upload whole folder or only i upload android platform data?

Comment: You only upload the www directory. Make sure that your config.xml file is inside.

Comment: hey i got error like "error intializing cordova: class not found" please help me

Comment: are you sure you have the config.xml file inside the www directory that you are uploading.  Also double check if the phonegap namespacing is correct.

Comment: Hey i edit with some change as par told by you. please make me correct in from this

Comment: in android eclipse its run perfectly. but when i build from cloud then only its splash screen is not display